# Elastic Beanstalk give error Root Object doesn't exist in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-web-services, elastic

I create a Jenkins job which uploads my war file to elastic beanstalk. But when I start to build it gives error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Root Object doesn't exist`

Below is my configuration:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because you used a variable ($) and wildcard name (*.war).

Elastic Beanstalk plugin does not support Variable or wildcard name in the Value.

I suggest a use full path of Jenkins job instead of `${WORKSPACE}` and full war name like `ROOT.war` instead of `*.war`